# Android - iterating through Zipentry

Tags: android, zip

I have large amount of files in a ZIP file (lets say 1000 images, some db files, binary files, ...). Inside it, I have some xml file I need to find and parse it. Information from it is shown to the screen. Problem is, when I am iterating through zip entry using:

```
   InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(zipPath);
   in = new ZipInputStream(inputStream);

   for (ZipEntry entry = in.getNextEntry(); entry != null; entry = in.getNextEntry()) {
     ...some code here...
   }
```

So when I am using Log.d, I see, it is iterating file by file, in case of large amount of files, it could take several minutes. Is there any better way, how to locate one specific file among others in ZIP file? "Brute force" approach I am using now is time consuming.

Thanks for any ideas

Waypoint

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zipfile.getInputStream(entry)));
```

Answer (score 0):

When extracting specific files, you should be using a `ZipFile`. In particular, [ZipFile.getEntry()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#getEntry%28java.lang.String%29).

This should be no problem since you are using a File. However, if you only have an InputStream (or you prefer to use ZipInputStream for some reason) then, if you control how the zip file is built, you should put the XML file as the first entry.